# Get multiselect attribute options in Magento category list page

Tags: magento, multi-select

I have this code:

```
<?php
  $multiSelectArray = $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('color');
  $lastItem = end($multiSelectArray);

  foreach($multiSelectArray as $multiSelectItem){
    echo $multiSelectItem;
    if($multiSelectItem != $lastItem) echo ", ";
  }
?>
```

to get multi-select attribute options in category list page.

My problem is that it don't show the attribute if there is only one option in the multi-select

Help !

Comment: May be related, I had a similar issue and ended up modifying the renderer that displays multi-options values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131380/display-multi-option-customer-attribute-within-customer-management-admin-grid

Comment: On a side note, why not use implode()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved because the only one option was a string, I have tested, if(is_string)........ show the first option ;)